# Binding to NSUserDefaults that Contains an Array of Dictionaries

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsuserdefaults, cocoa-bindings

I have an NSUserDefaults item that is an array of dictionaries. Each dictionary in this array corresponds to an object that defines the properties I care about on an NSMenuItem. One of those key/value properties in each dictionary is a boolean that defines whether the menu item should be shown or hidden. The key for this value is "show". Here's a visual example:

```
MenuItems      (Array)
  Item 0       (Dictionary)
    label      (String)      "Menu Item 1"
    show       (Boolean)     YES
  Item 1       (Dictionary)
    label      (String)      "Menu Item 2"
    show       (Boolean)     NO
```

In this case, the first menu item would be shown but the second wouldn't. I want this to dynamically update as user defaults change (through a preference pane).

Ideally I'd like to bind the "hidden" attribute on the NSMenuItem directly to the corresponding "show" value. Unfortunately, according to [NSMenuItem Bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CocoaBindingsRef/BindingsText/NSMenuItem.html), hidden is not something that can be bound. But I tried anyway, and am not sure what I'm doing will even work. The difficulty lies in the fact that this is an array of dictionaries, and it's not clear to me how bindings would work here. I have an NSArrayController bound to the sharedUserDefaults MenuItems, and I can see the various pieces of data through the arrangedObjects while debugging.

I've tried lots of things:

- Binding directly to the dictionary value
- Creating a wrapping NSObjectController for each dictionary and binding to the keypath "content.show"
- Observing the dictionary itself through addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context
- Observing the wrapped NSObjectController as described above.

None of these cause anything to happen. Observing the NSArrayController's arrangedObjects directly does, however, trigger observeValueForKeyPath:... but that's really not much different than just going for the whole hog and using NSUserDefaultsDidChangeNotification.

Is there a way to tackle this through bindings or KVO that will get me down to the level of detail I'm looking for?

Comment: I'm guessing the reason the NSObjectController approach doesn't work is that it's making a copy of the data and not tied to the original user defaults data.

Comment: I ran across a post somewhere else that led me to bind to a keypath of "arrangedObjects.show". That kind of works except the new value comes through as <null> to the observeValueForKeyPath: method *and* it gets called for *every* entry in the array as opposed to just the one that changed. I can pass the original index in as the context which works, but since it's being called for every item in the array it's rather inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

MenuItem hidden property can be bound, it's in the list of choices in IB.  However, you can't bind to an object in an array, there's now way to say, in effect, array.object1.  I think you could do what you want if you make your user defaults a dictionary of dictionaries -- the keys at the top level could be "menuItem1", "menuItem2", etc with the value being a dictionary with all the other keys you need.  It's hard to tell if this would work without knowing what else you have in your user defaults.  If it could work, you could get to the info you want with valueForKeyPath: like dict.menuItem1.show

Comment: I'll have to give that a try. Thanks for the idea. The sad part is that I have the other direction working (table view with check boxes bound to an array controller that is bound to user defaults). That's why I'm confused as to why it's not working in this direction. But I suppose I can change that to do the dictionary thing, too.